# Getting SharePoint users and comparing them with SPList

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a custom `SPList` that has a field `Assigned To`, now I can add as many items as I want, and they can have same title and same `User` they are assigned to, but what I want is a script so that I only get the distinct number of user's email address, e.g. if a user is assigned to more then 1 item, I will get there email address just once, here is the code I wrote down but I don't think if its good enough.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("www.local.com"))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList mySourceList = web.Lists["ListName"];

        SPQuery mySourceListQuery = new SPQuery();

        mySourceListQuery.Query =

            "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />" +
                     "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "</OrderBy>";



        SPListItemCollection mySourceItemColl = mySourceList.GetItems(mySourceListQuery);


        foreach (SPUser user in web.Users)
        {
            foreach (SPListItem mySourceListItem in mySourceItemColl)
            {
                name = mySourceListItem["AssignedTo"].ToString();

                name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf("#") + 1);

                if (user.Name == name)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(user.Email);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your code will process each item in `mySourceItemColl` for every user in the site. I would prefer to only go through the collection one time.

As such, I would write it more like this:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("www.local.com"))
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query =
            "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
            "</OrderBy>";
        SPitemCollection items = list.Getquery(query);
        List<string> emails = new List<string>();
        foreach (SPListItem item in items)
        {
            SPFieldUserValue value = 
                new SPFieldUserValue(web, item["AssignedTo"].ToString());
            if (null != value && 
                null != value.User && 
                !emails.Contains(value.User.Email)) 
            {
                emails.Add(value.User.Email);
                Console.WriteLine(value.User.Email);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The `my` prefixes are unnecessary, I'd call the variables `sourceList`, `sourceListQuery`, `sourceItems` etc.
2. I'd create a method for this:

   ```
   name = name.Substring(name.IndexOf("#") + 1);
   ```

   I guess `removeId` could be a good name. The method name would help readers to understand the intent of the writer.